# Tar extract error - implausibly old time stamp 1970-01-01 01:00:00

Tags: raspbian, debian, backup

I was create a tar script to make a backup of / directory on flash drive with exluding these folders:

> /lost+found - /mnt - /media - /proc - /sys - /tmp

Here's a fragment of script:

> sudo tar -zcpf $backup_dir/$now/backup.tar.gz /
>   --exclude=/lost+found/* --exclude=/mnt/* --exclude=/media/* --exclude=/proc/* --exclude=/sys/* --exclude=/tmp/*

And it was done without any errors, but when I wanted to restore this to test location to check that script is correct the screen shows information below

> tar: boot: implausibly old time stamp 1970-01-01 01:00:00

Here is a fragment of untar script

> sudo tar -xzpf $backup_source/$data/backup.tar.gz -C /home/pi/test

My problem is with unzip file to test location. OS: Raspbian (on raspberry pi) based on Debian

What I must do to unzip file correctly to directory /home/pi/test ?

Answer (score 6):

you may use "--warning=no-timestamp" to skip the timestamp check and allow full extraction of your archive (see http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/warnings.html for details).

however, that kind of error usually happens with corrupt archives, you'd better double check if all MD5/SHA checksums are correct and if your /boot folder really has files with very outdated time stamps.